# 3 tables left join task, order, and customer but can't get

Tags: mysql

The case study is like below,

> **Tasks** Table has an Order ID.
>   1 Task is belonged to an **Order** Table. An Order can have many tasks. Tasks Table does not have Customer ID information.
>
> **Order** Table has a Customer ID.
>   1 Order belongs to a **Customer** Table. A Customer can have many orders.

Now I want to generate a Task table to show the task is belonged to which customer.
However, my result is the column from the customer all is NULL. I confirmed my for customer_id is exist. Is it possible I do not store customer id in Tasks table? Since the Order Table already store the customer information.

```
select `tasks`.`id`, `tasks`.`created_date`, `tasks`.`due_date`, tasks.order_id, orders.id, orders.cust_id, 
customers.id, `customers`.`name`
from `tasks` 
left join `orders` on `tasks`.`order_id` = `orders`.`id` 
left join `customers` on `customers`.`name` = `orders`.`cust_id`
```

Is it something I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query has costumer name selected but you try to join it on costumer user_name. I suggest you to change both of them to correct column name **(name or user_name)** and try it that way. Eg(here i matched them with id after i edited):

```
select `tasks`.`id`, `tasks`.`created_date`, `tasks`.`due_date`, tasks.order_id, orders.id, orders.cust_id, 
customers.id, `customers`.`name`
from `tasks` 
left join `orders` on `tasks`.`order_id` = `orders`.`id` 
left join `customers` on `customers`.`id` = `orders`.`cust_id`
```

Working sql fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5835fd1/2

Answer (score 1):

could be you are joining the tables using the wrong column   try use user_id instead fo user_name

```
  select 
      `tasks`.`id`
      , `tasks`.`created_date`
      , `tasks`.`due_date`
      , tasks.order_id, orders.id
      , orders.cust_id, 
  customers.id, `customers`.`name`
  from `tasks` 
  left join `orders` on `tasks`.`order_id` = `orders`.`id` 
  left join `customers` on `customers`.`user_id` = `orders`.`cust_id`
```

Comment: yes, you are right... typo error... keep trying to fix it half of the day... silly mistake...